# How to enable cURL on Windows PHP5?

Tags: php, curl

I know this has been asked before but the thing is that I don't have a php.ini file in my PHP directory. There's only php.ini-development and php.ini-production. I removed the comment of extension=php_curl.dll in both of them but it still doesn't work.
I get this error when I try to use a PHP script with cURL:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_multi_init()

Comment: Look at the `phpinfo()` page to figure out where it belongs.

Comment: Ran <?php phpinfo();?>, it outputted a lot of information but there's nothing about php.ini in there.